# Issue of not playing video

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ashx, request.querystring

I have a issue on not playing video in play.aspx page im getting id in Url like this

```
play.aspx?id=1
```

when user get th play.aspx page for watch video i write a code in paly.aspx page on in html tag  below:

```
 <video src='<%# "VideoHandler.ashx?id=" + Request.QueryString["id"] %>'
 width="900" height="400" controls="" preload=""></video>
```

please let me know how can i load video in the Video player on run time is that i need to code 
like this.

So (assuming c#) in load event of page

```
    protected string getHandler(){
         return "VideoHandler.ashx?id=" + 
Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    }
```

and on HTML Tag

```
<video src='<%# getHandler() %> ' width="220" 
height="200" controls="" preload=""></video>
```

i try this in code but not worked. please help me to solve this issue and suggest me 
how can is do that if that possible to please hare you code of solution.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The client browser probably needs a full qualified URL to find VideoHandler.ashx, like "http://example.com/VideoHandler.ashx..."

Comment: now client will get Play.aspx page and there will be video load and VideoHandler.ashx is http helper to get video in <video></video> tag in asp.net